# jenkins parallel and series pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

[image: Blue ocean pipeline graph]

Is it possible that the above two consecutive stages will be in continuous series starting copy server1 stopservers server1 in one line rather than ending for each stage. Do we have a way where copy stopservers will have 4 parallel continuous executions unless like in the image where we have 4 parallel executions for each stage which starts before copy and ends after stopservers.Below is the case which iam looking for
-----------copy--------------stopservers-----------------------
|                                                   |
|----------server1-----------server1----------------|
|                                                   |
|----------server2-----------server2----------------|
|                                                   |
|----------server3----------server3-----------------|
|                                                   |
-----------server4----------server4-----------------
and my code is simple and is as below

```
node {  
   stage('copy'){  
       parallel 'server1': {  
                    echo "server1"  
       },  
       'server2': {  
            echo "server2"  
       },  
       'server3': {  
               echo "server3"  
        },  
       'server4': {  
           echo "server4"  
       }  
   }  
   stage('stopServers'){  
       parallel 'server1': {  
                    echo "server1"  
       },  
       'server2': {  
                    echo "server2"  
       },  
       'server3': {  
           echo "server3"  
       },  
       'server4': {  
            echo "server4"  
       }  
}
```

could you please let me know is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you only need one stage where each of its steps is a compound of a `copy` step followed by a `stopServer` step.

```
def copy(String server) {
    echo "copy $server"
}

def stopServer(String server) {
    echo "stopServer $server"
}

def servers = [ 'server1', 'server2', 'server3', 'server4' ]

node {
    stage('copy and stopServer') {

        // Construct the steps to run in parallel
        def parallelSteps = [:]
        def i = 0
        servers.each { server ->
            parallelSteps[server] = {
                // This is just to show that we don't wait for all the copy steps
                // before we start with stopServer
                sleep i++
                copy(server)
                stopServer(server)
            }
        }

        parallel parallelSteps
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks towel for your responce.
If two stages with compound of a copy step followed by a stopServer step is not possible could you please let me know how to code in jenkins pipeline script to have "one stage where each of its steps is a compound of a copy step followed by a stopServer step" as you said

Comment: I added an example to the answer - as you see you can add as many steps as you want for each server.